# Replace setInterval with jQuery Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have this kind of gui where I use setInterval to accomplish a simple kind for hover animation:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}

<table id="grid">
    <tr id="row_1"><td>row 1</td></tr>
    <tr id="row_2"><td>row 2</td></tr>
    <tr id="row_3"><td>row 3</td></tr>
    <tr id="row_4"><td>row 4</td></tr>
    <tr id="row_5"><td>row 5</td></tr>
    <tr id="row_6"><td>row 6</td></tr>
    <tr id="row_7"><td>row 7</td></tr>
    <tr id="row_8"><td>row 8</td></tr>
    <tr id="row_9"><td>row 9</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
    var rows = $('#grid tbody').children().map(function(i, e) {
        return $(this).attr('id');
    }).get();
    rows.reverse();

    var reverse = rows.slice().reverse();
    reverse.splice(0, 1);

    var mirror = rows.concat(reverse);
    var limit = mirror.length;

    var ctr = 0;
    var choose = setInterval(function(){
        var chosen = mirror[ctr];
        var prevpk = mirror[ctr - 1 < 0 ? limit : ctr - 1];

        $('#' + chosen).addClass('red');
        $('#' + prevpk).removeClass('red');

        ctr++;
        if (ctr >= limit) {
            ctr = 0;
        }
    }, 100);
</script>
```

What i want to know is how am I going to redo this using `jQuery animate` or any method that could still do same functionality instead of using the `setInterval` to loop over the child elements to hover?

[`Check Output Here.`](http://jsfiddle.net/mtLkppx7/1/)

Comment: do you mean setInterval?

Comment: i update my question.pardon. it should be setInterval. because i found out this setInterval is blocking

Comment: how could you use `animate` instead of `setInterval` and that to change the class of an element

Comment: animate is to perform a custom animation of a set of CSS properties. You are adding and removing classes.

Comment: so no other option to replace setInterval?

Comment: I think setInterval is best in this case.  It's not really an "animation" exactly, at least of the kind that JQuery supports ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with .animate, as animate has the ability to create a tween between a starting object property values and ending object property values.

Wither it is better to just use setInterval you will have to check that against how easy it is for you to understand/maintain the code and performance differences you may see with each one

1. Since you are not actually animating any element you will have to pass jQuery an object with a counter
2. As the property to animate just pass the same type of object with the ending property value
3. Then pass a second paramater setting the different options, at least `step` and `complete` in this case
4. On `complete` make a call to do the same animation in reverse

JS

```
function doAnimate(dir){
    var numele = jQuery("#grid td").length-1;

    //ternary if just deciding where to start the counter at
    var counter = {mycounter:dir==1?0:numele};

    //again ternary if deciding where to end the counter
    jQuery(counter).animate({mycounter:dir==1?numele:0}, {
            duration:1200,
            //step is called for each step in the tween
            step:function(stepValue){
                var index = Math.round(stepValue);
                var ele = jQuery("#grid td").eq(index);
                jQuery("#grid td.red").removeClass("red");
                ele.addClass('red');
            },
            complete: function(){
                //does a negation of the dir value (basically a quick toggle)
                doAnimate(-dir);
            }
    });    
}
doAnimate(1);
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mtLkppx7/7/)